Random Unicode characters being added to start of file after encryption/decryption
As per the title, not sure what I'm doing wrong. Using the pgpy Python module to encrypt/decrypt with 2048 bit RSA keypair, and consistently getting 'ï»¿' added to the start of the csv file.
After encryption and decryption, the first row (header row) goes from
OrderId,OrderItemId,OrderedDate,FirstName,LastName,Phone,CompanyName,Address1,Address2,Suburb,State,PostalCode,CountryCode,SKU,ProductTitle,Quantity,DispatchedDate,DispatchCarrier,TrackingCode

to
ï»¿OrderId,OrderItemId,OrderedDate,FirstName,LastName,Phone,CompanyName,Address1,Address2,Suburb,State,PostalCode,CountryCode,SKU,ProductTitle,Quantity,DispatchedDate,DispatchCarrier,TrackingCode 

.
import os
import pgpy

# Encypting file
key, _ = pgpy.PGPKey.from_file('C:\\Users\\\Administrator\\Sellerbox\\testkey.pub')
with open(os.getcwd() + '\\Orders.csv') as csv:
    file_message = pgpy.PGPMessage.new(csv.read())
    encrypted_file_message = key.encrypt(file_message)
    open(os.getcwd() + '\\Orders.csv.pgp', 'w').write(str(encrypted_file_message))


Converting it to a string did that. Solution: don’t.

create a binary file instead; or if you still want text then use something like base64 encoding (or any other binary serialization method)

Specifically, what happens if you change the last line to open(os.getcwd() + '\\Orders.csv.pgp', 'wb').write(encrypted_file_message)?

string ï»¿ looks like BOM (byte order mark). See Wikipedia: byte order mark. Maybe it needs to use open(..., encoding=...)

Python read csv - BOM embedded into the first key - Stack Overflow
